# Is there software that will help me convert my PST files into a searachable web archive?

Tags: linux, centos, debian

I have used POP3 for many and many years and always used PST files for back-up purposes. I'd like to be able to create a searchable mail archive of this 12GB worth of e-mail.

I had used Horde + Qmail for a while for searching e-mail, but it was truly horrible and even extremely slow when searching into a few ten thousands of e-mails, let alone more than a million.

I would prefer a free solution that would provide fast searching through historical e-mails. Also, preferably hosted on a server, so I don't have to worry about backing up any more crucial data on my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [MailArchiva](https://www.mailarchiva.com/home.jsp?page=features.htm) Open-Source and Enterprise editions for mail system deployments. It does have a feature that allows the import of a PST. The actual archive is searchable (using what they liken to "search engine technology"), and the archive compresses data and is smart about attachments and deduplication.

Answer (score 2):

First thing that came to my mind was using [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com).  Import your data via Outlook and connecting to the server via IMAP (FOSS version).  Zimbra searching is amazing and fast.  I have used 14GB plus across many mailboxes without any trouble.

EDIT: Instead of using IMAP to import the data, you can easily use the PST Import Wizard that comes with FOSS and NE editions.

Comment: No need to run IMAP. OSS edition also has the PST Import wizard. (Not the connector, though, which is different and of no use in this case.)

Comment: You are correct.  I totally forgot about that.  I have used it in the past and worked out great.